# pytest: custom mark with arguments

Tags: python, pytest

I would like to mark tests in the following fashion:

```
@pytest.mark.expectedruntime(100)
def test_function():
    blahblah()
```

And then run pytest with, for example, `-m not expectedruntime>50` (or some other syntax)

So that only tests with an expected run time of 50 or less would be run, or tests without that mark.

Is there a way to do this with native pytest/with a plugin? If not, what would I need to do in order to accomplish this?

https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html mentions a custom mark called "mark_with" which consumes arguments but doesn't mention how to actually use those arguments.

Comment: `pytest.mark` accepts any arguments (and stores them in the `args` and `kwargs` attributes), so your marker is already fine. However, if you want custom marker evaluation, you will need to implement it yourself.

Answer (score -2):

I hope this example will help http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/example/markers.html#custom-marker-and-command-line-option-to-control-test-runs

Comment: Please don't take it badly but your answer in its current form is of little value and if that link breaks, your answer would be completely useless to the future viewers. It is expected that answers provide explanation and examples and that links only point to more detailed information.